# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/Cipher

Tags: jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, snmp4j

I am implementing SNMP traps in JBOSS FUSE using log4j and unfortunately getting into an issue as follows.  Can any one please advise on what bundle/dependency I need to install to resolve this issue

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/crypto/Cipher
    at org.snmp4j.security.SecurityProtocols.addDefaultProtocols(SecurityProtocols.java:152)[244:AbstractionAPI:1.0.0]
    at org.snmp4j.Snmp.initMessageDispatcher(Snmp.java:225)[244:AbstractionAPI:1.0.0]
    at org.snmp4j.Snmp.(Snmp.java:251)[244:AbstractionAPI:1.0.0]

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.crypto.Cipher not found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [5]

Comment: What version of JBoss Fuse do you use?

Comment: JBoss Fuse (6.0.0.redhat-024)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this package isn't imported as optional dependency to pax-logging, as it is provided by the root bundle in Karaf. Therefore you should create a little fragment bundle that will adapt the pax-logging-service manifest, so this package can be imported.
The blog about adding [custom appenders](http://notizblog.nierbeck.de/2011/08/adding-custom-log-appender-to-pax-logging/) to Pax Logging might give you a hint on how to create this.

Comment: But this package is available as part of JRE.  It is included in jce.jar.  So how can I import a JRE library as a optional bundle

Comment: Not as optional bundle, but to add it to your package-import as optional dependency. Oh and maybe open an issue at the Pax Logging JIRA, so this is included from future on.

Comment: yeah seems like a good idea to have this improved in pax-logging